# After many channel strip demos

Tags: plug-ins, izotope, mixing

I think I've settled isotope alloy two is my favorite. Any thoughts? Is there anything anyone who's been using it for a long period of time has grown to hate?

I didn't have a lot of love for version 1, but 2 really seems to be nice. I think I may want to buy.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I really like ChannelStrip 3 by Metric Halo. Having the ability to make the GUI larger is really nice and the RRTA in the EQ section is very helpful. I've also been digging the Eventide Ultra Channel. They made it available for free a couple months back and I just started getting into it. The Omnipressor sections is sweet and the EQ curves sound amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I've been using it for long but it has quickly become a great channel strip tool in my music mixes. Ozone 5 has also become a great tool for me in mastering for music and post.  I like how the Isotope plugs are layed out, very clean and powerful.  Latency becomes an issue but is something I've just had to learn to accept and offset for when mixing music as I cannot stand protools delay compensation and mixing DSP and native on a strip makes it worse so I have been just staying native and slipping the audio the same samples as the delay.

Anyway, not sure if that helps, but yes, I've been using alloy often as a channel strip tool in music, not so much in post yet. I will say that the presets are real quick to drastically alter the color of your sound so I find myself trying not to go overboard with it.

Comment: Thanks for that brad. To be honest, while i usually love presets for music and i go through them a lot, for the post stuff i just haven't even explored them. It doesn't make as much sense to me, because they won't have this stupidly tight frequency cut mixed with mild compression. I really love the exciter on it though, subtle and nice.


Answer (score 0):

Alloy 2 is nice, but because it has so many dynamically switchable parameters, it can become a PITA to automate. Therefore, Metric Halo ChannelStrip is my favourite! All in one window, and a fixed amount of parameters. No. 2 goes to Avid's own ChannelStrip.

Answer (score 0):

i actually kinda liked alloy 1  better than 2nd...

Answer (score 0):

Ozone and alloy are loudness Tools! I use them for ultra compressed ad Voice overs and real Instruments in Electronic Music. It makes them Pop out of the speakers! 
Ozone is also a great mastering Tool if you want to use an unmastered track in a dj set.

For anything else i prefere waves!